# Eliminar líneas en un archivo .SRT en Python

Tags: python

Llevo poco tiempo aprendiendo Python e intenté de varias maneras modificar un archivo de texto, pero no pude, quiero eliminar una línea cada 4 líneas, son unos números consecutivos. Aquí está el código:

```
from io import open

modificar=open("archivini.srt", "r+")

n=0
m=0

while n<8:
    
    moverse=modificar.readlines()

    moverse[m]=" "
    modificar.seek(0)

    modificar.writelines(moverse)

    m=m+4
    print(m)
    n=n+1

modificar.close()
```

En esta imagen se pueden ver algunas de las líneas que quiero eliminar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los subtítulos en los archivos .srt pueden tener más de una línea de texto, por lo que eliminar una de cada cuatro lineas no va a funcionar en el caso general.

```
1
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:07,000
Downloaded from
YTS.MX

2
00:00:08,000 --> 00:00:13,000
Official YIFY movies site:
YTS.MX

3
00:00:11,105 --> 00:00:15,323
An Eiji OKUDA Film

4
00:00:38,205 --> 00:00:43,480
SHŌJYO

5
00:01:22,712 --> 00:01:28,427
Based on a novel by
Mikihiko RENJO
```

La manera segura de eliminar la numeración de los subtítulos es reconocerlos apoyados en las siguientes características:

- Van en secuencia creciente.
- Son el único contenido de la línea.
- Están precedidos de una línea en blanco.

Tampoco es conveniente reemplazar el archivo de entrada; si hay algún problema en el proceso, lo pierdes.

```
modificar = open("archivini.srt", "r")
salida = open("salida.srt", "w")

linea_previa_en_blanco = True
secuencia = 1
for linea in modificar:
    contenido = linea.strip()
    if contenido == str(secuencia) and linea_previa_en_blanco:
        secuencia += 1
    else:
        salida.write(linea)
        linea_previa_en_blanco = contenido == ""

modificar.close()
salida.close()
```

**Demo**

archivini.srt

```
1
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:07,000
Downloaded from
YTS.MX

2
00:00:08,000 --> 00:00:13,000
Official YIFY movies site:
YTS.MX

3
00:00:11,105 --> 00:00:15,323
An Eiji OKUDA Film

4
00:00:38,205 --> 00:00:43,480
SHŌJYO

5
00:01:22,712 --> 00:01:28,427
Based on a novel by
Mikihiko RENJO

6
00:01:39,286 --> 00:01:41,127
Good morning.
Screenplay by
Izuru NARUSHIMA and Katsuhiko MANABE

7
00:01:41,127 --> 00:01:44,433
Screenplay by
Izuru NARUSHIMA and Katsuhiko MANABE
```

salida.srt

```
00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:07,000
Downloaded from
YTS.MX

00:00:08,000 --> 00:00:13,000
Official YIFY movies site:
YTS.MX

00:00:11,105 --> 00:00:15,323
An Eiji OKUDA Film

00:00:38,205 --> 00:00:43,480
SHŌJYO

00:01:22,712 --> 00:01:28,427
Based on a novel by
Mikihiko RENJO

00:01:39,286 --> 00:01:41,127
Good morning.
Screenplay by
Izuru NARUSHIMA and Katsuhiko MANABE

00:01:41,127 --> 00:01:44,433
Screenplay by
Izuru NARUSHIMA and Katsuhiko MANABE
```